# Characterization of the trace function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that the trace of a matrix is a linear map for all square matrices and that $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\operatorname{trace}(BA)$ when the multiplication makes sense.

On the [Wikipedia page for trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29), under properties, it says that these properties characterize the trace completely in the following sense: If $f$ is a linear function on the space of square matrices satisfying $f(xy)=f(yx)$, then $f$ and $\operatorname{tr}$ are proportional. A [note on the bottom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#cite_note-2) of the page gives the justification, but I do not understand the logic of it. Thanks

Comment: The word linear means, here, $f(A+B) = f(A) + f(B),$ and, for a constant $c,$ also $f(cA) = c f(A).$

Comment: In the note of the bottom of the wiki page, $e_{ij}$ means the matrix with $(i,j)$-entry being equal to $1$, and all the other entries are zero.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for your response, but I am having trouble understanding the proof in general, not just what the symbols stand for.

Comment: As explained in Wikipedia, the key point is that the space $ \mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$ of matrices with zero trace is one-dimensional, and  $M_n(k) =: \mathfrak{gl}_n(k) = \mathfrak{sl}_n(k) \oplus k$ satisfies $[ \mathfrak{gl}_n(k),  \mathfrak{gl}_n(k)] =  \mathfrak{sl}_n(k)$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The proof in that footnote depends on the following facts that were left out.

1. If $i\neq j$, then $[e_{ii},e_{ij}]=e_{ii}e_{ij}-e_{ij}e_{ii}=e_{ij}-0=e_{ij}$. So we can write $e_{ij}$ as a commutator $e_{ij}=xy-yx$ and thus $f(e_{ij})=f(xy)-f(yx)=0.$
2. If $i\neq j$, then similarly $[e_{ij},e_{ji}]=e_{ii}-e_{jj}$, and we get that
   $$
   f(e_{jj})=f(e_{jj})+0=f(e_{jj})+f([e_{ij},e_{ji}]=f(e_{jj}+(e_{ii}-e_{jj}))=f(e_{ii}).
   $$

Answer (score 37):

Let $f$ be such a map and $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a one in $(i,j)$-entry and zero elsewhere. We have

$$E_{ij}E_{kl}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0, &\mbox{ if } \; j \neq k
\\E_{il}, & \mbox{ if } \; j=k\end{array}\right.$$

Therefore, if $i\not=j, \; E_{ij}=E_{i1}E_{1j},$ then by hypothesis,

$$f(E_{ij})=f(E_{i1}E_{1j})=f(E_{1j}E_{i1})=f(o)=0,$$

and

$$f(E_{ii})=f(E_{i1}E_{1i})=f(E_{1i}E_{i1})=f(E_{11})$$

for each $1 \leq i \leq n.$

Now, let $C=\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}a_{i,j}E_{ij}$ be a vector in the above basis, then

$$f(C)=\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}a_{ij}f(E_{ij})=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}f(E_{11})=f(E_{11})\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}=f(E_{11})tr(C).$$

Comment: I was searching all over the internet for an easy and understandable answer to this question. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, we are given a function on square matrices of a fixed size, call it $f,$ with three properties, square matrices $A,B$ and constant $c.$ So:
$$f(A + B ) = f(A) + f(B),   $$
$$ f(AB) = f(BA),    $$
$$ f(cA) = c f(A).$$

As Paul pointed out, the notation $e_{ij}$ means the matrix with a 1 at position $ij$ and 0 everywhere else.

There is some value for $f(e_{11}).$ E do not know what that is.

First,for some $i \neq 1,$ define
$$ S_i = e_{i1} + e_{1i}      $$
The main thing is that
$$ S_i e_{11} S_i = e_{ii}   $$
and $$  S_i^2 = I. $$
So
$$  f(e_{ii}) = f(S_i (e_{11} S_i)) = f( (e_{11} S_i) S_i) = f( e_{11} S_i^2) =  f(e_{11}).   $$

Next, with $i \neq j,$ we use
 $$ e_{ii} e_{ij} = e_{ij} $$
while
$$  e_{ij} e_{ii} = 0,  $$ the matrix of all 0's.

Begin with any $B,$
$$f(0) = f(0B) = 0 f(B) = 0.$$

Now, for any $i \neq j,$
$$ f(e_{ij}) = f(e_{ii} e_{ij}) = f(e_{ij} e_{ii}) = f(0) = 0. $$

Finally, if the entries of $A$ are $A_{ij},$ we have
$$ A = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n  A_{ij} e_{ij},  $$ so
$$  f(A) = f(\sum_{i,j = 1}^n  A_{ij} e_{ij}) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n  A_{ij} f(e_{ij}) = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii} f(e_{ii}) = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii} f(e_{11}) =  f(e_{11})  \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii} =   f(e_{11})  \mbox{trace} A         $$