# Characterisations of traces on $F(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, trace, operator-ideals

Let r be a linear form (not necessarily continuous) on the Operators on a separable Hilbert Space $H$ with finite Rank $F(H)$ such that $\operatorname{r}(AB)=\operatorname{r}(BA)$ whenever $B$ is any Operator and $A\in F(H)$.
I want to show, that $r$ coincides with a scalar multiple of the usual Trace defined by $Trace(\sum<.,x>y)=\sum<y,x>$

If i had continuity, i think i could try something similar to what is done here:
[Characterization of the trace function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104854/characterization-of-the-trace-function).

Is this result still true, if $r$ is not assumed to be continuous, and how to prove that?

Comment: I stongly doubt that it is always true when $r$ is not continuous and $H$ is infinite-dimensional. The general problem with these types of definitions is that you can divide $F(H)$ up into subspaces such that $r$ satisfies your formula on each of the subspaces, but with different scalar multiples. These subspaces are dense, so when you have continuity, you can argue that the multiples have to be the same. But without continuity, you can't.  I say this "in general" because I have not verified that your particular problem fits this pattern. Maybe you'll get lucky. but I doubt it.

Comment: I cannot really post an answer to my question yet, because my apparent prove of the fact uses some heavier machinery from someone elses unpublished paper, but it seems to be True.
You show, that <.,x>x has the same trace for all normed x, by translating those into each other using isometrys, and then use some partial diagonalization to show, that r(<.,x>y)=<y,x>*r(<.,a>a) for some a.