# $V=\mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{F})$, $f\in V^{*}$ with $f(AB)=f(BA),$ exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ with $f(A)=\lambda\textrm{tr}(A)\,\forall \,A\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dual-spaces

Let $V=\mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ the space of $n\times n$ matrices. Let $f\in V^{*}$ satisfying $f(AB)=f(BA).,$ So, exists unique $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $f(A)=\lambda\textrm{tr}(A)\,\forall \,A\in V$, where $\textrm{tr(A)}$ denotes the trace of $A\in V$.

Any tips to follow will help me. I think that $\lambda$ has something to do with the eigenvalues of $A$, but I don't know.

Comment: The idea is to prove that the span of matrices $AB-BA$ is the set of trace zero matrices.

Comment: Another (related) idea is to play around with $f(E_{ij}E_{kl})$ and the hypothesis and get some nice results concerning $f(E_{ij})$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, how could I prove that?
Can you give just some hints?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104854/characterization-of-the-trace-function